# Select column values based on an if condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a empty df like this .

```
dfSummary=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Company Type' , 'Max_Val', 'Min_Val'] , dtype=str)
```

I have a variable CompanyType which can have two values let's say 'public' or 'private'. I am analyzing data for both  company type and want to fill in df with another variable value maxValue if companyType = 'private' and minVal if companyType = 'public'. 
I create a tempdf with values and concat that with dfSummary.

```
tempdf=pd.DataFrame({'CompanyType':companyType, 'max Val': maxVal,'min Val': minVal }, index=[0])
dfSummary=pd.concat([dfSummary,tempdf])
```

I want to initialize temdf in pythonic way , with 'max Val' or 'min Val' based on company Type . in other words I want to have if condition when i create tempdf. Please help.

Comment: You should understand that `dfSummary` has 3 columns, so whatever you are concatenating it with must also have 3 columns. If minVal is to be entered, what will be the value of the Max_Val column?

Comment: one of the minVal or maxVal will be null based on companyType value. I want to do with if condition when I create dfTemp , in same line.

Comment: What version of python are you using?

Comment: Python = 2.7.5 and pandas = '0.16.2'

Comment: Look below for a solution. vvvv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
col = [companyType] + ([maxValue, np.nan] 
             if companyType == 'public' else [np.nan, minValue])    
df = pd.DataFrame([col], columns=['Company Type' , 'Max_Val', 'Min_Val'])
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC

**Setup**

```
dfSummary = pd.DataFrame(
    [['public', 'a', 'b'],
     ['private', 'c', 'd'],
     ['public', 'e', 'f'],
     ['private', 'g', 'h'],
     ['privage', 'i', 'j']],
    columns=['Company Type' , 'Max_Val', 'Min_Val'],
    dtype=str
)

dfSummary

  Company Type Max_Val Min_Val
0       public       a       b
1      private       c       d
2       public       e       f
3      private       g       h
4      privage       i       j
```

---

**Solution 1**
`np.where`

```
dfSummary.assign(
    New=np.where(
        dfSummary['Company Type'] == 'public',
        dfSummary.Max_Val, dfSummary.Min_Val)
)

  Company Type Max_Val Min_Val New
0       public       a       b   a
1      private       c       d   d
2       public       e       f   e
3      private       g       h   h
4      privage       i       j   j
```

---

**Solution 2**
With `pd.Series.where`

```
dfSummary.assign(
    New=dfSummary.Max_Val.where(
        dfSummary['Company Type'] == 'public',
        dfSummary.Min_Val)
)

  Company Type Max_Val Min_Val New
0       public       a       b   a
1      private       c       d   d
2       public       e       f   e
3      private       g       h   h
4      privage       i       j   j
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I'm just not sure it is what OP wanted, but it still deserves some +1.